# Choosing to Leave Closed due to a question being a duplicate doesn't give you the option to share the dupe target URL

Tags: bug, review-queues, reopen-review

I just did this task in the Reopen Queue: https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/30360787

I've seen this before where someone is having trouble because they aren't doing anything to distinguish two or more elements from each other. So I choose Leave Closed with the reason:

> This question has been answered, is not unique, and doesn’t differentiate itself from another question.

However, it then just finished the task without giving me the option of saying which specific question I think it should be the target duplicate.

Is this intended behavior? If other reviewers also think it's a duplicate, how will the close message get updated to show the user which question they can find their answer on?

Comment: eh, well, it's the reopen queue, you can't exactly cast a close vote on it.

Comment: Related on meta.SE: [When choosing to leave closed for the duplicate reason in the reopen review queue, allow specifying another duplicate target](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/369987/756727)

Comment: @GinoMempin I should have thought to check the Uber Meta.

Comment: As a workaround, you can leave a comment...but agreed that the experience could be better.

Comment: Even not in review queues, it would be great if we could add dupe targets to already closed questions - lots of times a question gets closed by lazy close votes when they could have been dupes, but once the question is closed there's no more opportunity to link it to other dupes.  Closed duplicates are useful because they act as funnels via search traffic for questions that are tricky to search for - the more linked duplicates the more likely it is that everyone will find what they're looking for.